# Admin and User Login C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm using Access db. I need to validate if its Admin or user because I want to open different forms for them. But I can't find a way to do it. I used a checkbox to register if the employee is admin or not like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strincon = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\flavi\Desktop\Pet&Shop.2\PetShop\TelaAbertura\bin\Debug\DatabasePS.mdb;Persist Security Info=True";

        string comando = "INSERT INTO Funcionario (Nome,  Login, Senha, Email, Cargo, Admin) Values (@Nome, @Login, @Senha, @Email, @Cargo, @Admin) ";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strincon);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(comando, con);

        com.Parameters.Add("@Nome", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNome.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Login", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLogin.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Senha", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSenha.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Cargo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCargo.Text;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Admin", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = checkBox1.Checked;
```

This is working fine, but in the login form there's no difference because I don't know how to validate the checkbox  with the login and password, so it's like this.

```
         OleDbDataAdapter da;
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select  * from Funcionario where Login='" + txtLogin.Text + "'and Senha= '" + txtSenha.Text + "'", con);  //Senha = Password
         da.Fill(dt);
         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
             FrmPrincipal frm = new FrmPrincipal();
             frm.Show();
             this.Visible = false;
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Login ou Senha Inválidos", "Ocorreu um Erro de Autenticação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             txtLogin.Clear();
             txtSenha.Clear();
         }
```

Comment: The short answer would be : you have to check the username, password and privilege from the database. then based on the privilege, you can do whatever you want !

Comment: Why are you properly using parameters in the first block of code and then wrongly concatenating strings on the second? Always use parameters! Also, what happens when you run the second block of code? It doesn't seem incorrect, you just need to get the value of the Admin column

Comment: So it's better to use Parameters? I'm new to c# so thank you. Both of them are working fine, but in the second one I coudn't find a way to validade if its admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    // you should have one row in the table. check for admin.
    if(dt.Rows[0]["Admin"] == true)
    {
         etc.
```

As stated in the comments, add parameters to your adapter's query. **Always** use parameters. They are used to "clean" user input, if someone is trying to hack your database.